# vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 1886417008) >= this->size() (which is 256)

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

This function helps visualize the Y, U, and V channels of the input image.
`input_image` is the YUV input image, `u_colormap` is the map to visualize the u channel, and `v_colormap` is the map to visualize the v channel.

I am using the colormap as a lookup table, and then I will save the new value from the colormap into the channel array, and then assign the value to the output_image.

When I compile the code, I don't get any errors, however when I run the code I get the error

> vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 1886417008) >= this->size() (which is 256)

Does anyone have an idea where the mistake could be?

```
void show::display_channels(const Mat &:input_image, const std::vector<std::vector<int> > u_colormap,
                                            const std::vector<std::vector<int> > v_colormap,
                                            std::vector<Mat> &output_image) {

    Mat channel[3]; 
    cv::split(input_image,channel); 
    cv::cvtColor(channel[0],output_image[0], CV_GRAY2BGR);
    //Y is already grayscale and I can convert it to BGR without using colormaps                            

    for (int i = 0; i < output_image.rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < output_image.cols; j++) {
            output_image[1].at<int>(i,j) = u_colormap.at(1).at(channel[1].at<int>(i,j));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1886417008 is 0x‭70707070‬. Way too regular. I'd check and see if this is some sort of debugger code for uninitialized memory. Also worth checking on any arrays you're loading with 0x70s (112 decimal) for buffer overflows.

Comment: @user4581301 don't understand what you mean with way too regular. and how do I check my arrays with 0x70s?

Comment: @makoto `0x70707070` is a pattern of repeating `0x70`s (`'p'` chars). That pattern is too regular to be accidental. And you should check if you have any arrays that YOU are filling with `0x70` values, make sure you are not going out of bounds of those arrays into surrounding memory.

Comment: makoto, my apologies for being too rushed and unclear in my comment. @RemyLebeau thank you for clarifying for me.